# What do you want from bitcoin faucets?

Tags: faucets

I operate a very high potential bitcoin faucet. Currently it is the highest paying faucet (only available for mobile). I know faucets are considered passe, but many people still use them. Im curious, what features would you like the most from faucets?

Comment: You could create multi lingual faucets and focus on attracting users from countries where Bitcoin is currently less known. Most people on this StackExchange are not brand new to Bitcoin and therefore are unlikely to be using faucets. It would be easier to answer your question if you told us what your goal is. Are you trying to help adopting? Or are you focused on making money by selling ads or other services?

Comment: I'm trying to make a faucet that actually is useful, helps spread bitcoin, and make maybe a little money (at least something to cover server costs)

Answer (score 3):

Privacy and security are important to Bitcoin users, so I would like to see more faucets that do not:

1. Use Flash
2. Use JavaScript
3. Contain any advertisements
4. Require the collection of any personal data to use the faucet

Comment: What if the app only collects an email address to know who to associate the btc with?

Comment: @Dri that would be a big improvement over most existing options. As long as you are telling your users what information is being collected I see no problem with it. In fact I can see the reason why some steps may need to be taken to prevent abuse from bots designed to abuse your faucet.

Comment: Okay well so far mine does all of this already. only ads that do show are the one the user requests to see. Let me know if you have anymore ideas.